# SQL Server add a linked server to postgres database

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, linked-server

I am trying to connect a PostgreSQL to SQL Server server as a linked server.

On the SQL Server, I have installed the ODBC driver for PostgreSQL (psqlodbc_09_02_0100-x64). I created a system DSN to a specific database on the PostgreSQL. This DSN work correctly.

Using SSMS I created a linked server that created successfully.
When I test the connection it says successful and when I expand I can see all the tables from postgres.

However when I try selecting from one of those tables it goves me the error:
The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "ServerName" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.

I googled around but did not find anything that was helpful for me.
Can someone please help me with this.

Thank you

Comment: Look in the PostgreSQL server's log file to see if it reported any errors.

Comment: that is highly configurable, so I don't know.  How did you install PostgreSQL?  What OS are you running it on?

Comment: This is my select I'm running in SSMS: Select * from openquery(LINKED_SERVER_NAME,'Select * from Database.schema.tablename')

Comment: Error is cross-database references are not implemented. What do I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

**PostgreSQL**:

1. You  must provide a **database name** in the Data Source **DSN**.
2. Run Management Studio as **Administrator**
3. You must **omit the DBName from the query**:

   `SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([LinkedServer], 'select * from schema."tablename"')`